# ngFor input text filter angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

I want to have the user to be able to type in keywords to filter items within menuitems in an input field. I am unable to insert ngModel, was wondering if there is a work around for this? This should be done dynamically as well using no buttons

```
<div class="launch-switch-popup" [class.hidden]="!isActive">
     //INPUT OF SOME SORT GOES HERE
    <div class="launch-switch-item" *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
        <img class="icon" [src]="item.icon"> 
        <p class="launch-switch-title">{{item.text}}</p>
        <br>
        <div class="plugin-row" *ngFor="let child of item.children" (click)="clicked(child)">
            <p>{{child.text}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codeburst.io/create-a-search-pipe-to-dynamically-filter-results-with-angular-4-21fd3a5bec5c

Comment: try material auto complete

Answer (score 0):

[mat-autocomplete-filter-input](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tab-and-autocomplete)

HTML:

```
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
                {{option}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

TS:

```
 myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Owo', 'Ohree','Ope', 'Owk', 'Oyree'];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```